# How to use json.net to Deserialize a nested class?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following class

```
 public class CallbackResultsJson
    {
    public class CallbackResults
    {

        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string Data { get; set; }
        public string Log { get; set; }
        public string StatusText { get; set; }
        public string TransactionToken { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am trying to use Json.Net to Deserialize requestbody but I am always getting a null for status,data. **any ideas why ?**

```
var requestbody =@"
{
    "CallbackResults":
    {
        "TransactionToken":"b65524-qwe",
        "Status":0,
        "Message":"Publish Application to QaLevel Operation Completed",
        "Data":[],
        "Log":["sucess"
    },
    "RequestNumber":"REQ1234"
}"

var TransactionResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CallbackResultsJson.CallbackResults>(requestBody);
```

Comment: In your JSON, `Status` is an integer, not a string, `Data` is an array, not a string, `Log` is a badly formed array (no end bracket). You should get an exception with this JSON, and even if you fix the array for `Log`, you will get an exception because of the mismatch of types.

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Please post actual code, this code won't even compile because of the badly formed string (you use `"` inside the string but should use `""`), you're missing a semicolon, and the class names you're using in the deserialization call doesn't match the example class above. You've basically retyped the problem here and made additional errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a little bit of change should be done.
Your class:

```
public class CallbackResultsJson
{
    public CallbackResultsClass CallbackResults { get; set; }
    public string RequestNumber { get; set; }

    public class CallbackResultsClass
    {
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string[] Data { get; set; }
        public string Log { get; set; }
        public string TransactionToken { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Your data:

```
var requestbody = @"
        {
            ""CallbackResults"":
            {
                ""TransactionToken"":""b65524-qwe"",
                ""Status"":0,
                ""Message"":""Publish Application to QaLevel Operation Completed"",
                ""Data"":[""Data1"", ""Data2""],
                ""Log"":""sucess""
            },
            ""RequestNumber"":""REQ1234""
        }";


        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CallbackResultsJson>(requestbody);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your class needs to have a property of the sub-type,

```
public class CallbackResultsJson
{
    public CallBackResults CallbackResults { get; set; }

    public string RequestNumber { get; set; )

    public class CallbackResults
    {

        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string Data { get; set; }
        public string Log { get; set; }
        public string StatusText { get; set; }
        public string TransactionToken { get; set; }
    }
}

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CallbackResultsJson>(requestBody);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used json2csharp.com to convert requestbody to c# classes and it generated these classes.it worked

```
 public class CallbackResults
    {
        public string TransactionToken { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public List<string> Data { get; set; }
        public List<string> Log { get; set; }
    }

    public class CallbackResultsRootObj
    {
        public CallbackResults VdiCallbackResults { get; set; }
        public string RequestNumber { get; set; }
    }
  var vdiTransactionResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CallbackResultsRootObj>(requestBody);
```